# Why do my wipers only operate at high speed?

Tags: volvo, windshield-wipers

I have a 2003 Volvo XC90, and the wipers now only work at high-speed, regardless of the stalk setting.

The normal order is off - intermittent - low - high; however now they go to high speed for all 3 switch settings.

The single sweep (put the stalk up from the off position) still works.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely cause - the stalk switch is faulty, and rather than moving through the three different positions it just closes the high speed circuit.

You should be able to replace the stalk switch easily and cheaply - find one at a breaker's yard.